# Custom RPC sized array parameters

Tags: rpc, json-rpc, custom-rpc, types, substrate-node

I have `custom RPC`, which looks like so

```rust
#[rpc(client, server)]
pub trait SomeRpcApi {
    #[method(name = "some_submitData")]
    async fn submit_data(
        &self,
        id: u64,
        message: [u8; 32],
    ) -> RpcResult<()>;
}
```

and I'm trying to call it using this TS script

```typescript
const api = await ApiPromise.create({
    provider: wsProvider,
    rpc: {
        some: {
            submitData: {
                description: '',
                params: [
                    {
                        name: 'id',
                        type: 'u64'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'message',
                        type: '[u8; 32]'
                    }
                ],
                type: 'RpcResult<((), u32)>'
            }
        }
    }
});
const message = new Uint8Array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32]);
const id = api.createType('u64', 1);
const data = api.createType('[u8; 32]', message);
const resp = await api.rpc.time.submitForSigning(id, data);
```

bun on submitting I'm getting this error:

> RPC-CORE: submitData(id: u64, message: [u8; 32]):
> RpcResult<((), u32)>:: -32602: invalid type: string
> "0x1ddf7f02f19991b8e2b56d7e325f05835bb1d66b5c0d87ba98b4230f2a28c085",
> expected a sequence at line 1 column 68

Where's the issue here? Thanks.

Comment: Dont know if that is what is causing the issue; but the return type looks different.

Comment: changing it makes no difference to error - used this one from one of similar questions as this seem to work for other folks.

Comment: tried changing it to `Vec<u8>` and getting this error on it's construction: `Error: createType(Vec<u8>):: Bytes: required length less than remainder, expected at least 14281, found 32`

Comment: Could you please share the code? Its always difficult to debug such things remotely.

Comment: Can't share code. From latest findings - if sending u16...u64 it works. if sending u8 - it considers as a string. `polkadot-v0.9.30` if that helps. `Vec<u8>` works with 10 bytes at most, and then error...

Answer (score 1):

`[u8; 32]` is basically an array of u8. Try directly with the array you have:

```js
    const message = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32];
  
    const id = api.createType('u64', 1);
    
    const resp = await api.rpc.time.submitForSigning(id, message);
```

Comment: tried everything, including `Array.from(U8Array)` to make sure it's array. I assume problem might be somewhere at Codec::encode() -> RPC method, which does not Vec<u8>::decode().

Comment: It worked for me like this, without Polkakdot JS where you able to request the RPC some_submitData succesfully?

Comment: apparently there's some `compactFromU8aLim` function called before sending, which produces my error.

Comment: Then it needs the Uint8Array type as an input: https://github.com/polkadot-js/common/blob/master/packages/util/src/compact/fromU8a.ts#L72

Comment: How you discover this is the method that throws the error?

Comment: Only working way for me is json encode arrays into strings, and decode on RPC side. Everything else I've tried delivers data in incorrect formats...

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass message as an `array[u8; 32]` not as a `hex string`.